# $(this).attr({class: "activeTab"}); is not working because this is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

This is my JS code, the problem I have is the one in the title. It seems as though $(this) is returning undefined.:

```
function load() {
    $(".inactiveTab").attr("onclick", "clickInactiveTab()");
}

function clickInactiveTab() {
    $(this).attr("class", "activeTab");  
}
```

The html is the following:

```
<div class="inactiveTab">Tab 1</div>
<div class="inactiveTab">Tab 2</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the way one sets up event handlers with jQuery:

```
function load() {
  $(".inactiveTab").click(clickInactiveTab);
}
```

Your code was such that the handler code (`"clickInactiveTab()"`) would be interpreted as a function body. Because the code called your actual handler function without any explicit context, the value of `this` would be either `undefined` or `window` (depending on whether you're in "strict" mode).

In my opinion a better practice would be to set up the handlers as delegated handlers from the `<body>`:

```
$("body").on("click", ".inactiveTab", clickInactiveTab);
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much!!! Your answer was really helpful and i didn't know what you teached me :)

Answer (score 1):

With pure JS

```js
function load() {
    for(var i = 0; i< inactiveTabArray.length; i++){
       inactiveTabArray[i].classList.remove("activeTab")
    }
    this.classList.add("activeTab")
}


var inactiveTabArray = document.querySelectorAll(".inactiveTab");

for( var inactiveTab = 0; inactiveTab< inactiveTabArray.length; inactiveTab++){
     inactiveTabArray[inactiveTab].addEventListener("click", load, false)
}
```

```css
.activeTab{color: red}
```

```html
<div class="inactiveTab">Tab 1</div>
<div class="inactiveTab">Tab 2</div>
```